# Do I have to inherit from abc.ABC to use the @abstractmethod decorators?

Tags: python

Is it possible to use the `@abstractmethod` decorator in any class definition to signal a method to be defined later, or do I have to have `abc.ABC` as a base/meta class for this to work properly?

Comment: Have you tried using this decorator without inheriting from `ABC`?

Comment: Yes and nothing happened, I want to make sure, though. Absence of bad results doesn't mean I'm doing it correctly.